# Android: WIFI on and off app crashing (JAVA)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app to toggle WiFi On and Off. I have the following code. Everytime I run it, it crashes. Cant understand why. API - 26

This is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fahad.test;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ToggleButton toggleButton;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.turn_on_off_wifi_programmatically);

    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
            if (checked) {
                textView.setText("WiFi is ON");
                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            } else {
                textView.setText("WiFi is OFF");
                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

    if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
        textView.setText("WiFi is ON");
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    } else {
        textView.setText("WiFi is OFF");
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
}
}
```

Please assist me with this. Thanks

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this permission to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```